# R - My conditional and nested for loop take too long. How to vectorize?

Tags: r

I have the following code for a for loop which contains a conditional if-statement this included the last 10 loop cycles to search for a change in logical pattern, and increment a counter on true:

```
for(ii in 100:sp) 
{
     if(start(ii) == 1 && mean(start(ii-11:ii-1)) == 0)
     {
          count = count + 1
     }
}
```

the value of sp is **3,560,400**; meaning a loop of 3 million plus times. The load time is enormous, about 40 minutes for execute the loop.

How can I optimize this code using perhaps vectorization?

Thank you for your help.

**Edit**

I have included all of my code here so everyone can see what is happening:

```
# store the current directory
initial.dir<-getwd()
# change to the new directory
setwd("H:/R/range")
# load the necessary libraries - sound
library(sound)
library(TTR)

#####################################################
# LOAD .WAV FILE / SET OUTPUT FILE
#####################################################

# set the output file
sink("rangetmp3.out")

# load the dataset
sndSample <- loadSample('range.wav')
FS <- rate(sndSample)
nBits <- bits(sndSample)

# assign sound wave
Y <- sound(sndSample)



#####################################################
# CONSTANTS
#####################################################

#(m/s) speed of light
c <- 3E8 

############################
# |- Radar parameters
############################

#(s) pulse time
Tp <- 20E-3

# number of samples per pulse
N <- Tp*FS

#(Hz) LFM start frequency for example
fstart <- 2260E6

#(Hz) LFM stop frequency for example
fstop <- 2590E6

#(Hz) LFM start frequency for ISM band
fstart <- 2402E6

#(Hz) LFM stop frequency for ISM band
fstop <- 2495E6

#(Hz) transmti bandwidth
BW <- fstop-fstart

#instantaneous transmit frequency
f <- seq(fstart, fstop, length=N/2) 

#range resolution
rr <- c/(2*BW)
max_range <- rr*N/2

#####################################################
# RANGE
#####################################################

############################
# |- The input appears to be inverted
############################

trig <- -1*Y[1,]
s <- -1*Y[2,]

#reset Y
#Y = 0

############################
# |- Parse the data here by triggering off rising edge of sync pulse
############################

# reset counter / threshold
count <- 0
thresh <- 0

# assign logical vector that meets thresh

start <- (trig > thresh)

sp <- NROW(start)-N

for(ii in 100:sp) 
{
     if(start(ii) == 1 && mean(start(ii-11:ii-1)) == 0)
     {
          count = count + 1
     }
}
```

**Edit #2: Matlab loop**

```
for ii = 100:(size(start,1)-N) 
    if start(ii) == 1 && mean(start(ii-11:ii-1)) == 0 
        count = count + 1; 
        sif(count,:) = s(ii:ii+N-1); 
        time(count) = ii*1/FS; 
    end
end
```

Comment: do you mean to use the function `start()` or do you have a vector/list named `start` and you mean to index it, ie `start[ii]` ?

Comment: Also, have a look at `?":"`   I believe you need two pairs of parenthesis there, and thus the mean value you are calculating is of a completely different set of numbers:   use eiteher  `(ii-11):(ii-1)` or better yet,  `ii-(11:1)`.   This last paren is not needed, but helps with readability

Comment: It must be meant to be an index, since (as I understand it) `start()` will return `1 1` for any integer. So as it stands the first part of the `if()` would be true for every case, but I think throwing a warning at each iteration!

Comment: the start is a matrix i believe which included the following:

Comment: start <- (trig > thresh)

Comment: @Resso, it looks like `trig` is a single-dimensional vector, and hence `start` will be as well.  See this line:  `trig <- -1*Y[1,]`

Comment: thank you, i am very new to R, and trying to convert a Matlab script to R, and unsure of how to proceed. I will include the matlab loop and maybe that will help? Editing OP now

Comment: Okay it has now been edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a <s>single line</s> two lines, as follows:

```
library(TTR)
shiftIndx <- c(6:length(start), 1:5)
count <- sum(start == 1  &  SMA(start, n=11)[shiftIndx] == 0, na.rm=TRUE)
```

*where `SMA`  is from the `TTR` packages*

#### Here is an explanation, piece by piece

```
## this will give you a logical vector of T/F
##    whose length will be equal to length of start
start == 1

## This part give you a smiple moving average of every 11 numbers
SMA(start, n=11)

## We need to shift these over so that they are centered properly. 
##   `shiftIndx` takes the first `floor(11/2)` MA's and puts them at the tail. 
##    (notice that these will be NA.)
shiftIndx <- c(6:length(start), 1:5)
SMA(start, n=11)[shiftIndx]

## .. checking if it is equal to 0 will give you another T/F vector, 
##     also of length equal to the length of start
SMA(start, n=11)[shiftIndx]  == 0

## Then combining the T/F vectors using `&` gives another T/F vector 
##   of the same length, but is TRUE only where _both_ of the original 
##   vectors are TRUE
(start == 1)   &   (SMA(start, n=11)[shiftIndx] == 0)

## Taking the `sum(.)` of a logical vector is the equivalent of counting
##    how many TRUE values are in the vector. 
## Snce you are incrementing `count` every time both conditional statements are TRUE, 
##    the final value of `count` will be the same as the sum below
sum( (start == 1)   &   (SMA(start, n=11)[shiftIndx] == 0), na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

```
And here are some benchmarks (before the edit of adding `shiftIndx`)

set.seed(7)
for (N in 10^(6:8)) {
  cat("N is: ", N, "\n")
  start <- round(rnorm(N, 0, 10))    
  print(system.time(
    count <- sum(start == 1  &  SMA(start, n=11) == 0, na.rm=TRUE)
  ))
  cat("count is ", count, "\n", rep("~", 14), "\n\n", sep="")
}

## OUTPUT: 

N is:  1e+06 
   user  system elapsed 
  0.059   0.021   0.081 
count is 485
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

N is:  1e+07 
   user  system elapsed 
  0.578   0.195   0.768 
count is 4889
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

N is:  1e+08 
   user  system elapsed 
  7.808   5.716  19.392 
count is 49737
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, however my output is: [1] NA - perhaps there is a problem with my initial code?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, unfortunatley I'm getting an output of: [1] 0

Comment: I have included all of my code in the OP if it may help? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Thanks @flodel for the catch.  I think the second argument missing was just a typo from when I pasted the correction but has been cleaned.

Comment: @Resso, is it possible that `0` is the correct count?  Why dont you try creating a smaller, artificial data set where you can manually check the correct output and then use that to test against the code.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I have the Matlab dataset to compare. Basically what the loop is doing is if last sample is 1 and the last 11 consequented samples = 0 then we have a rising edge. Start is a logical (true false) vector (about 3 million count). Then the loop will store the 'rising edge' if it is met into a separate vector sif and time, which will be plotted on a graph.

Comment: here is the output of your vectorization code: http://i.imgur.com/njfuOFd.png - thats printing start, followed by count

Comment: @Ricardo, the problem is that your moving average includes index `ii`. You'll have to lag it by `1`.

Comment: @flodel, you are right, my MA is off.  But I'm not sure it's by 1.  I think it has to be shifted by `floor(11/2)`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta unfortunately the same results, here it is: http://i.imgur.com/gytUkG0.png

Comment: @Resso, that output is not the entirety of the output.  Use `tail(<someobject>, 12)` to see the last 12 values

Comment: @RicardoSaporta here is the pastebin of the 'start' vector (only half of it as pastebin has a 500kb limit), but u can see it's like pulses of true and false: http://pastebin.com/pGDYja1K

Comment: HI @Resso, I am very sorry, but I do not wish to look at a three hundred million long vector to help trouble shoot your code.  Please take the time to create a small sample data and use that to confirm that the above is working for the small portion in question. If so, then you can confirm that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta here is the output with your new code: http://i.imgur.com/qO1lMKM.png

Comment: Resso, you do not have to mark the answer as accepted if it did not resolve your question. My point was that simply pasting a giant dump of an output of a portion of a vector does not help any in resolving any issues.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I'm sorry I thought the start vector might help, as it's basically just an oscillating true false vector. I've marked the answer as accepted, as I think it would help others - I don't know where to go from here with my code, really lost atm :(

Comment: Resso, start by having a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info   and read through the documentation.  Specifically, read through indexing vectors and the differences between lists, vectors, matricies and data.frames.   You have pasted matlab code into R, and the syntax, although appears similar has very different meanings. Specifically with regards to parens/braces, indexing, the colon operator, etc.

Comment: OP is looking for something like `sum(tail(start == 1 & runSum(start, n=12) == 1), -99))`. And @Ricardo, your solution is producing NA again, why do you not test your code?

Comment: @flodel, mostly because I was writing at 5am and less than sharp.  But also because I am trying to carve out some time to lend a hand here while also working on my other projects and hence I have less than an ideal amount of time.  Thanks as always for catching my ommissions

Comment: @flodel thank you! would you mind looking at my other thread? It's similar to this where someone was very kind to convert the matlab nested loop into R, ready to be vetorized - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514964/r-convert-this-nested-for-loop-matlab-to-r?noredirect=1#comment23711278_16514964