# R - Convert this nested for loop (MATLAB) to R

Tags: r

I need to convert this for loop into R

```
for ii = 100:(size(start,1)-N) 
    if start(ii) == 1 && mean(start(ii-11:ii-1)) == 0 
        count = count + 1; 
        sif(count,:) = s(ii:ii+N-1); 
        time(count) = ii*1/FS; 
    end
end
```

The start vetor is a single dimension vector of true and false values about 3 million elements in total.

As loops in R take a long time, it take about 3 hours to execute the code, so it needs to be vectorized.

If someone could help I would be really really appreciate it.

**Edit**

Here is my R code with just a simple count (which takes hours to execute)

```
for(ii in 100:sp) 
{
     if(start(ii) == 1 && mean(start(ii-11:ii-1)) == 0)
     {
          count = count + 1
     }
}
```

**Edit-2**

Here are the dummy values:

`start`:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

`N`:

```
[1] 882
```

`FS`:

```
[1] 44100
```

`s`:

```
[1]  1.762390e-01  1.797791e-01  1.826172e-01  1.795044e-01  1.724243e-01
[6]  1.665039e-01  1.640625e-01  1.634827e-01  1.628723e-01  1.606750e-01
```

Comment: It sounds like you already have some R code written (that takes 3 hours to run). Could you show that code? It would make the problem clearer

Comment: @DavidRobinson Sure thing :) I have edited the original question

Comment: can you provide a complete, reproducible example? you can create dummy values for `start`, `s`, `sif`, `N`, `FS`, `count` etc.

Comment: What is `start(ii)` supposed to do? If `ii` is just a single number, that will always return `0 0`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson The script use a .wav file to loop through a single channel and note rising edges, used by a small tin can radar. looking at the logic vector starting at 100, if last sample is 1 and the last 11 consequented samples = 0 then we have a rising edge. If so, populates our result vector with N Samples (pulsewidth) of the Right channel Wav-samples.

-e4e5f4 I have included the sample/dummy data.
Thank you very much guys!!

Comment: if it helps, here is the original matlab script im trying to convert to R, http://pastebin.com/7s8frcBS

Comment: Its a bit confusing, should we concentrate on your `R` code or `Matlab` code? Indexing in `R` is done using `[]` not `()`. Also add dummy data as part of the code, like `start = c(rep(TRUE,10), rep(FALSE,10))` and so on.

Comment: I would like that Matlab for loop converted to R, perhaps if you could rewrite it correctly to R, as I have made a mistake it appears. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you mean `start(ii)` to be `start[ii]`?

Answer (score 1):

I just created some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1234)
start = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 300000, replace=TRUE)
N = 882
count = 0
```

Your `R` code takes:

```
system.time(
for(ii in 100:(length(start)-N)) 
{
  if(start(ii) == 1 && mean(start((ii-11):(ii-1))) == 0)
  {
    count = count + 1
  }
})

## user  system elapsed 
## 15.42    0.00   15.43
```

There is a function in `R` called `start` and it was getting called instead of indexing the vector `start`. The correct and faster way is:

```
system.time(
  for(ii in 100:(length(start)-N)) 
  {
    if(start[ii] == 1 && mean(start[(ii-11):(ii-1)]) == 0)
    {
      count = count + 1
    }
  })

## user  system elapsed 
## 2.04    0.00    2.04
```

Comment: All the same, can't this be done in a single vectorized statement by using `rollmean` or something similar?

Comment: @e4e544 thanks mate - certainly the start function in R was definitely a problem! However, as mentioned, with 3 million elements to the start vector, run time is huge. Is there any chance you would be able to vectorize the for and nested if statement? I'm having real trouble with this. Thanks so very much
    user  system elapsed 
    26.54    0.00   27.05 
    [1] 1905

Comment: @Resso, apparently it has already been answered. Did you try that solution?

Comment: @e4e5f4 hi I don't see the other solution, could you please reference it? And thank you.

Comment: by the way your loop works perfectly e4e544! My other thread was just to vectorize the count, but as you can see I need the whole loop vectorized. Your loops works great, it's just that it takes 30 seconds to execute.

Comment: @e4e5f4 however i still need to convert this line `sif(count,:) = s(ii:ii+N-1); `

Comment: for now you can simply add those 2 lines of code. `sif[count,] = s[ii:(ii+N-1)];` and `time[count] = ii*1/FS;`. If it is unreasonably slow, we can try to vectorize. I am a not a fan of premature optimization at the cost of code readability/maintainability.

Comment: @e4e5f4 I get the following errors:
`Error in sif[count, ] <- s[ii:(ii + N - 1)] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix` - I had the same code, been trying to troubleshoot it for a very long time.

Comment: @e4e5f4 btw the problem is with `sif[count, ]`, if put say `xyz[count,] <- 40`, i get `object 'xyz' not found`, do I have to declare it first?

Comment: yes, create a matrix with `0`s or use an empty matrix with `rbind` (which will be very slow)

Comment: @e4e5f4 I tried all of the follow: `xyz <- 0` and `xyz[] <- 0`, and `xyz[,] <- 0` and `xyz <- rbind()`, still that same errors message: `Error in xyz[count, ] <- 40 : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`

Comment: create a matrix of `0`s with required number of rows and columns... `xyz = matrix(0, 100, 10)` will create a `100x10` matrix of all zeros.

Comment: @e4e5f4 Thankyou. I created the matrix with the number of rows I needed, and now i get `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, count, , value = c(0.0489501953125, 0.047882080078125,  : 
  subscript out of bounds`. I have a feeling I am never going to be able to reproduce this for loop in R. Just problem after problem, some 48 hours now spent trying to reproduce 4 lines of code.

Comment: indexing is exceeding the max row/col. like for ex, you are trying to access element [4,2] in a 3x3 matrix. Probably you need to come up with a reproducible example & post as a separate question.